# Graphics issues after amdgpu tinkering: "dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):"

Tags: drivers, dpkg, amdgpu

2 days ago, my graphics driver apparently crashed while opening an mp4 file in VLC - something I have done several times before. Otherwise, the computer remained usable. At the time, syslog showed these errors:

```
Aug 13 22:49:45 beepbeep kernel: [50420.530049] mmap: qtdemux0:sink (43166): VmData 2664718336 exceed data ulimit 2630227705. Update limits or use boot option ignore_rlimit_data.
Aug 13 22:49:49 beepbeep rtkit-daemon[1519]: Supervising 10 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
Aug 13 22:49:49 beepbeep rtkit-daemon[1519]: Supervising 10 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: [00005618a8681580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2207]: unable to update icon for vlc
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: [00007eff380044d0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: [00007eff380044d0] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Aug 13 22:49:50 beepbeep org.gnome.Nautilus[43217]: [00007eff4d9919a0] avcodec decoder: Using Mesa Gallium driver 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 for AMD Radeon RX 6600 (navi23, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.49, 6.2.0-26-generic) for hardware decoding
Aug 13 22:50:00 beepbeep kernel: [50435.990342] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring vcn_dec_0 timeout, signaled seq=22, emitted seq=24
Aug 13 22:50:00 beepbeep kernel: [50435.990927] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process vlc pid 43217 thread vlc:cs0 pid 43239
Aug 13 22:50:00 beepbeep kernel: [50435.991557] amdgpu 0000:0c:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!
Aug 13 22:50:01 beepbeep kernel: [50436.298174] [drm] Register(0) [mmUVD_POWER_STATUS] failed to reach value 0x00000001 != 0x00000002
Aug 13 22:50:01 beepbeep kernel: [50436.535052] [drm] Register(0) [mmUVD_RBC_RB_RPTR] failed to reach value 0x00000060 != 0x00000270
Aug 13 22:50:01 beepbeep kernel: [50436.772011] [drm] Register(0) [mmUVD_POWER_STATUS] failed to reach value 0x00000001 != 0x00000002
Aug 13 22:50:01 beepbeep kernel: [50436.861316] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Aug 13 22:50:01 beepbeep kernel: [50436.861320] WARNING: CPU: 23 PID: 41263 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_irq.c:600 amdgpu_irq_put+0xa4/0xc0 [amdgpu]
```

And it went on for a while, I think the bigger issue came when I tried to fix it today. I went to AMD's website to get the latest drivers, and ended up downloading `amdgpu-install_5.5.50503-1_all.deb`.

For reference, my OS version: `uname -a` shows

```
Linux beepbeep 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I went through the installation process detailed on AMD's website, and saw these errors:

```
Building initial module for 6.2.0-26-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
```

I'm not savvy enough to understand what `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/make.log` is telling me, but here's the output

```
DKMS make.log for amdgpu-6.0.5-1620033.22.04 for kernel 6.2.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Tue 15 Aug 2023 08:22:31 PM EDT
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/scheduler/sched_main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/scheduler/sched_fence.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/scheduler/sched_entity.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/drm_gem_ttm_helper.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_tt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_bo.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_bo_util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_bo_vm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_module.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_execbuf_util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/symbols.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_range_manager.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/drm_buddy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_kernel_params.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_resource.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/dma-buf/dma-resv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_pool.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_backlight.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_device.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_sys_manager.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_ioctl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_kthread.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_io.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_perf_event.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_seq_file.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_agp_backend.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_device.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_suspend.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_kms.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_pci.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_atombios.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_memory.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_sched.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amddrm_ttm_helper.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fence.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fence_array.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/atombios_crtc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_reservation.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amddrm_buddy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_cache.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_connectors.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/atom.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_auth.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_fb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fence.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ttm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_object.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_print.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_gart.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fbmem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_encoders.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_display.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_i2c.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_crtc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_connector.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_atomic_helper.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/ttm/amdttm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_device_cgroup.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mn.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/scheduler/amd-sched.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_modes.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_gem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_time.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_ftrace.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_acpi_table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_page_alloc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_numa.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fs_read_write.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_aperture.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_simple_kms_helper.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_bitmap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ring.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_vmscan.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_cs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_dma_fence_chain.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bios.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_benchmark.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mce_amd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_workqueue.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_cpumask.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/atombios_dp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_dsc_helper.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_afmt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_hdcp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_debugfs_inode.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_trace_points.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/atombios_encoders.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_sa.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_sysfs_emit.o
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c: In function ‘amdgpufb_create’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c:236:16: error: implicit declaration of function ‘drm_fb_helper_alloc_fbi’; did you mean ‘drm_fb_helper_alloc_info’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  236 |         info = drm_fb_helper_alloc_fbi(helper);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                drm_fb_helper_alloc_info
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c:236:14: warning: assignment to ‘struct fb_info *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  236 |         info = drm_fb_helper_alloc_fbi(helper);
      |              ^
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c:264:73: error: ‘struct drm_mode_config’ has no member named ‘fb_base’
  264 |         info->apertures->ranges[0].base = adev_to_drm(adev)->mode_config.fb_base;
      |                                                                         ^
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/atombios_i2c.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_dma_buf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_vm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_vm_pt.o
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c: In function ‘amdgpu_fbdev_destroy’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c:306:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘drm_fb_helper_unregister_fbi’; did you mean ‘drm_fb_helper_unregister_info’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  306 |         drm_fb_helper_unregister_fbi(&rfbdev->helper);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         drm_fb_helper_unregister_info
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:260: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/amdkcl.o
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:512: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:2026: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic'
```

Something I read online said to attempt going into recovery mode and trying to fix broken packages, this failed with a similar dpkg error.

I... I'm sorry. I really screwed up here :'(

Do I just need to reinstall at this point? Can't figure out any other way forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you begin, you may need to uninstall the amdgpu-dkms package:

```
sudo apt remove amdgpu-dkms
```

##### I was having trouble with this as well and it seems like I was able to get the dkms to build by installing some packages first:

```
sudo apt install amdgpu-dkms-firmware amdgpu-dkms-headers libdrm-amdgpu-dev libdrm-amdgpu-dev linux-hwe-6.2-tools-common linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 amdgpu-lib autoconf automake initramfs-tools shim-signed
```

I also installed the Linux kernel source package for the hwe kernel (that I am running). So I searched for available packages (you may have to have sources enabled in your software settings).

```
apt-cache search hwe | grep source
```

and then selected the one that matched the one I'm running on 20.04 (linux-hwe-5.15-source-5.15.0) so for you it will be different (for 6.2 instead of 5.15).

And then I ran sudo apt install amdgpu-dkms

When that was okay (and it did take a long time to compile), I then proceeded to use the installer and ran

```
amdgpu-install --accept-eula
```

##### If none of this works, you can still back out and uninstall everything.

First, run the uninstaller:

```
amdgpu-uninstall
```

If it says nothing is installed, just remove the amdgpu-dkms at least:

```
sudo apt purge amdgpu-dkms-firmware amdgpu-dkms-headers amdgpu-dkms
```

and then purge the installer

```
sudo apt-get purge amdgpu-install
```

and reboot.

Please let me know if you have any problems in the comments.

Comment: BTW, you can get the amdgpu driver running without installing the downloaded version from AMD. It is built in but you usually have to blacklist the radeon driver if amdgpu is not in use. `lspci -k | grep -A3 VGA` should tell you what kernel driver is in use and running `apt-cache search amdgpu` should help you locate any related packages like drm and libva related stuff. If you need any help with that then just open another question.

Comment: Thank you, this did solve my biggest issue of fixing amdgpu-dkms. I'd note that I was never able to run `amdgpu-uninstall`, as the command wasn't found, but removing it, installing those packages, and reinstalling it, then running `amdgpu-install --accept-eula` did get my graphics back to normal upon a reboot.

My original issue does seem to still be present; opening files in VLC leads to a crash.

Comment: Aha~! I realized I've had an image-adjust video effect applied in VLC, leading to a crash most times I open video files. By unapplying the effect, I am now able to open all files again.

Comment: @BenForTheFirstTime FYI, the "dry run" option: `amdgpu-install --dry-run` is really helpful so you can run before installing to see if there would be any conflicts or errors before trying to install. I used this a few times and kept getting a DKMS error so I knew something was wrong. Downloaded the amdgpu-dkms package, extracted the files and cd into the `/usr/src/amdgpu-6.1.5-1609671.20.04/amd/dkms/` directory an from there I ran `./configure` to manually do what DKMS would do, got an error saying that the kernel source was missing, so I searched for and installed the kernel source package.

Comment: @BenForTheFirstTime The other packages I figured would be for good measure as packages will often fail to compile if you're missing a needed `-dev` package. So I did an `apt-cache search amdgpu | grep "\-dev"` and saw there was some drm packages (drm is referenced in the dkms errors). The autoconf and the rest was just a guess considering that's what was used there (note the configure.ac file if you look at the file list for `dpkg -L amdgpu-dkms | grep src`).